# Let $a_n$ be the sequence of all decimal numbers over $N$ contains only the digits $1$ and $0$. show $\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be the sequence of all decimal numbers over $N$ contains only the digits $1$ and $0$.

I am trying to show $\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}$ converges.

Im not really sure how to use the definiton of converges or any of the standart theorems to show convergence of this sequence.

Is there any way, at all to use the standart methods to show this series converges?

thanks.

Comment: As written, it's very hard to tell what you mean. In particular, what does "decimal numbers over $N$" mean? All interpretations I'm coming up with have uncountably-many members, so cannot comprise the entries of any sequence, much less a unique sequence. Also, all such interpretations so far include $0$ as one of the members, which causes obvious problems.

Comment: @CameronBuie I imagine the intended meaning is "positive integers."

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For each $m$, count the number of $a_n$ with exactly $m$ digits; let this number be $b_m$. Then the contribution of $a_n$ with exactly $m$ digits is at most
$$\sum_{a_n\text{ has $m$ digits}}\frac1{\sqrt{a_n}}\leq \sum_{a_n\text{ has $m$ digits}}\frac1{\sqrt{10^{m-1}}}=\frac{b_m}{\sqrt{10^{m-1}}}.$$
Can you use this to show that the series converges?

Comment: Yes, Thank you.